# Triggering action from a select using jquery and php

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

i'm having a problem with jquery and php, mainly php :S
i have a select populated via php, that's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<select name="gname" id="gnome">
<option>Scegli...</option>
<?php 
include ('php/config.php');
//recupero organizzazioni dal database
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT gname, count(*) as number
        FROM gtdb
        WHERE `country` = 4 OR `country` = 103 OR `country` = 107 OR `country` = 219 OR `country` = 210 OR `country` = 210 OR `country` = 153 OR `country` = 110 OR `country` = 200 OR `country` = 102 OR `country` = 95 OR `country` = 173 OR `country` = 228 OR `country` = 152 OR `country` = 97 OR `country` = 94 
        GROUP BY gname
        HAVING number >= 20
        ORDER BY gname";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $mysql);
while($nome = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {  
?>

<option value= "<?php echo $nome['gname'];?>" ><?php echo $nome['gname']; ?></option>
<?php  
    };   
?> </select>
```

when i select an option, this jQuery function should post the value of the option to a php script and append the result into a "result" div.
jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#gnome').change(function() {
        var inpval=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/query.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {valor : inpval},
            success: function(data) {
                $('.result').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP code:

```
<?php 
    include('config.php'); //database connection(works)

    $org_name=$_POST['valor']; 
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gtdb WHERE gname LIKE '$org_name%'");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $row['name'];
    }
?>
```

Actually i'm able to connect to the database, do a query and populate the select, but when i select an option nothing happens, i don't know if it's fault of the jquery code or of the php code, any help?
Thanks in advance :)

EDIT: html code that reaches the browser, for user3558931

```
<p>gname</p>
<select name="gname" id="gnome">
    <option>Scegli...</option>

<option value= "Al-Aqsa Martyrs Brigade" >Al-Aqsa Martyrs Brigade</option>

<option value= "Al-Nusrah Front" >Al-Nusrah Front</option>

<option value= "Al-Qa`ida in Iraq" >Al-Qa`ida in Iraq</option>

<option value= "Al-Qa`ida in the Arabian Peninsula (AQAP)" >Al-Qa`ida in the Arabian Peninsula (AQAP)</option>

<option value= "Baloch Liberation Army (BLA)" >Baloch Liberation Army (BLA)</option>

<option value= "Baloch Republican Army (BRA)" >Baloch Republican Army (BRA)</option>

<option value= "Free Syrian Army" >Free Syrian Army</option>

<option value= "Gunmen" >Gunmen</option>

<option value= "Hamas (Islamic Resistance Movement)" >Hamas (Islamic Resistance Movement)</option>

<option value= "Haqqani Network" >Haqqani Network</option>

<option value= "Individual" >Individual</option>

<option value= "Islamic State of Iraq (ISI)" >Islamic State of Iraq (ISI)</option>

<option value= "Lashkar-e-Islam (Pakistan)" >Lashkar-e-Islam (Pakistan)</option>

<option value= "Lashkar-e-Jhangvi" >Lashkar-e-Jhangvi</option>

<option value= "Militants" >Militants</option>

<option value= "Other" >Other</option>

<option value= "Palestinian Islamic Jihad (PIJ)" >Palestinian Islamic Jihad (PIJ)</option>

<option value= "Popular Front for the Liberation of Palestine (PFLP)" >Popular Front for the Liberation of Palestine (PFLP)</option>

<option value= "Popular Resistance Committees" >Popular Resistance Committees</option>

<option value= "Sindhu Desh Liberation Army (SDLA)" >Sindhu Desh Liberation Army (SDLA)</option>

<option value= "Southern Mobility Movement (Yemen)" >Southern Mobility Movement (Yemen)</option>

<option value= "Taliban" >Taliban</option>

<option value= "Tehrik-i-Taliban Pakistan (TTP)" >Tehrik-i-Taliban Pakistan (TTP)</option>

<option value= "Unknown" >Unknown</option>
</select>
```

And yes, it's about terrorism XD

Comment: I don't know if its the SO editor but in your select query you have `‘’` and they should be `''`

Comment: did that, but still not working :(

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in developer tools to make sure that you're ajax is actually sending?

Comment: are you getting some jquery error in console ?

Comment: No error in jQuery console nor in the network tab

Answer (score 3):

Please change:

```
data: ({valor : inpval}),
```

To:

```
data: {valor : inpval},
```

And the statement obtaining the data value should be:

```
var inpval = this.value;
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/ceNJG/)

When you change the select value please open dev tools and check the network tab and you'll see that the ajax call is made.

Also make sure you have an element with the class `result` is on the page.

**NOTE**: Your PHP script needs to be edited so it can return something, maybe `echo $row['gname'];`

Comment: Can you provide the HTML that reaches your browser, for the first piece of code in your post.

Comment: i'll add it at the end of the main post... oh, i haven't made the graphic part yet, so it's just a "skeleton" of main part of the entire project

Comment: See demo and additional comments in my answer.

Comment: when i select a value nothing happens in the network tab, but i have no idea why, the jquery function seems good, any idea?

Comment: Is that in the demo I provided or in your own page? If your own page, check the console tab for any errors. Is your page public so I can take a look?

Comment: in the demo you have provided gives an error because query.php doesn't exists, here is the link you requested http://testingme.altervista.org/progettolpw/index.php

Comment: with the mod you suggested to the jquery function selecting an option within the select triggers a query, but no data are returned

Comment: That simply means your PHP script `php/query.php` is not returning a result or returning a blank string. To confirm put `alert(data)` in the success callback. You'll see an alert with nothing in it. ... Have your script return something .... I can tell that since you do not have any `echo` statement, nothing will be returned to the calling script. You want to have something like `echo "$row['name']<br/>";`

Comment: ok, adding the echo and the alert command in the scripts and testing gives me that:
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in <b>/Users/Shin/Sites/progettolpw/php/query.php</b> on line <b>7</b><br />

Comment: ok, now it works, i changed $row['name']; to echo $row['gname'];
LOL
i'll edit the question with the working code :)

Comment: Great!! Glad you figured that out ... enjoy, hoping you've learned a few new tricks.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 var inpval=this.value;
```

to

```
 var inpval=$(this).val();
```

its the right jquery syntax to get the value from fields.

Comment: query.php is in the same folder as config.php

Comment: why are you including query.php file in select. its should not be included, try removing it as its is in your jquery ajax function.

Comment: did you add a div with a class attribute of value 'result' ?

Comment: because of the success function in the jQuery ajax call, that function is supposed to add the result of the query in the .result div

Comment: where is your closing tag of select?

Comment: it wasn't showed in the code above, i edited it, but in the php page is all ok

Comment: did you load jquery script in your php?

Comment: do you mean in the index.php page? yes i did, i'll edit the code to add that part, check it out

Comment: yes and also add your jquery function in the same index.php page.

Comment: i think that something bad could be in the last part of the jQuery ajax call, in the success function that should put the results of the query into the div, don't you?

Comment: the jQ function is imported as a script in the second link tag in index.php, i tried also adding it directly into the page, but nothing changed...

Comment: debug your query if it is giving any results, i think the second query not returning any result.

Comment: how? with the developer console of chrome?